# What would be the preferred way to show data in spreadsheet cells?

Tags: support, formatting

Which would be the preferred format for answers involving data in spreadsheets, a table or a picture?  Below is an example based on one of my answers.

### Table

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 8 | 10 |
| 2 |  |  |
| 3 | 4 | 10 |
| 4 |  |  |
| 5 | 2 | 22 |
| 6 |  |  |
| 7 | 1 | 7 |
| 8 | 2 | 6 |
| 9 | 2 | 7 |
| 10 |  |  |
| 11 | 1 | 24 |
| 12 |  |  |
| 13 | 0 | 26 |
| 14 |  |  |
| 15 | 0 | 26 |
| 16 |  |  |
| 17 | 0 | 5 |
| 18 | 3 | 10 |
| 19 | 3 | 5 |
| 20 |  |  |
| 21 | 1 | 5 |
| 22 | 3 | 8 |
| 23 | 3 | 5 |
| 24 |  |  |
| 25 | 1 | 6 |
| 26 | 12 | 6 |
| 27 |  |  |
| 28 | 2 | 22 |
| 29 |  |  |
| 30 | 4 | 18 |
| 31 |  |  |
| 32 | 8 | 10 |

### Picture

[image]

Comment: A table is better IMO since you can copy it, but can you decrease the size a bit? The question is rather long because of that table, and I don't think removing the last ~10 rows would hurt.

Answer (score 2):

I think the table is a good thing, but I'd also include an easily copyable JSON version, that is white-space formatted over multiple lines to resemble a table.

Also, for the table, you could bold the leftmost column to indicate that it is a header column.

A properly formatted JSON table could for example be:

```json
[[   8,  10],
 [null,null],
 [   4,  10],
 [null,null],
 [   2,  22],
 [null,null],
 [   1,   7],
 [   2,   6],
 [   2,   7],
 [null,null],
 [   1,  24],
 [null,null],
 [   0,  26],
 [null,null],
 [   0,  26],
 [null,null],
 [   0,   5],
 [   3,  10],
 [   3,   5],
 [null,null],
 [   1,   5],
 [   3,   8],
 [   3,   5],
 [null,null],
 [   1,   6],
 [  12,   6],
 [null,null],
 [   2,  22],
 [null,null],
 [   4,  18],
 [null,null],
 [   8,  10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Adám that a table is probably best. Images may not be loaded sometimes, and you can't copy from them. However, if the table gets extremely big (like the one in your question), I would suggest linking to [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) or somewhere else.